# jQuery tablesorter plugin column width incorrect in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-7, tablesorter

I am using the tablesorter plugin (http://tablesorter.com) and am having a problem with column widths in IE7. It looks fine in Firefox and sometimes in IE7.

Here's a screenshot of the problem:

[IE7 View](http://imagebin.antiyes.com/index431.html)

and here's how it's supposed to look:

[Firefox view](http://imagebin.antiyes.com/index432.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a common layout problem in IE.  If you are using CSS to style the columns width, also add the column widths to the td tags.  Set the first column to a percentage that will try to suck up most of the space, like 50% or something.  The first column width will take everything that it can and the other columns will abide by their static width.